# WHERE with two tables and specific table name

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables:

```
table 1 named table_1
table 2 named table_2
```

in the Table 2 I have a column with a name "table_name" where I have names of some tables from dbase

I want to write a condition for WHERE procedure, something like that (wrong of course)

```
WHERE $table_1.name of table 1 = $table_2.table_name
```

ie the situation when the proper name of the Table 1 is inside column table_name from the Table 2

of course - the proper name of the Table 1 is -> $table_1

Comment: This often (but not always) indicates poor schema design... you might find this problem entirely disappears with a little restructuring of your data.

Comment: we have a solution for this problem but in another my question. A little from backside :)) but all is working fantastic. Thanks all for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to do <sub>(Thanks gosh)</sub>

In any widely used DBMS

Comment: Not quite true, but +1 for the "thanks gosh". It's possible to do it horribly and dynamically ( in Oracle at least ).

Comment: @Ben: it is not possible in **sql**. But indeed, in pl/sql, t-sql and even in mysql stored procedures it is possible to do ;-)

Comment: @zerkms - people looks for help in finding solution for his problems. I think, it will be fine not only said - it's impossible, but show real working solution, maybe from another direction of view. Generally, thank you, couse your negative comment push me to look at the problem from another point and I have now a right solution. Thank you.